# Formula to show only cells with a value and remove blank rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list that's two columns wide that has blank rows in then I'm trying to make a second list that shows only the rows with text in column "B" if column "C" also has a value at the same time removing the blank rows. For example here's my list:

[image]

sheet 1 is my list and list 2 is how I would like it to look.

I'm correctly using this formula:

```
=IF(ROWS($B$4:B4)>COUNTA($B$4:$B$13),"",INDEX($B$4:$B$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$4:$B$13)-ROW($B$4)+1)/($B$4:$B$13<>""),ROWS($B$4:B4))))
```

which removed the blank rows but it shows black cells in column "C" for example:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just use autofilter on your original list to filter out items with no quantity?

Comment: i need the original list to always have some of the same items on it as i will only be changing the qty on it and then printing the results.

Comment: When you filter, the original items don't go away. The rows are just hidden.  When you need the full list, just remove the filter criteria, and you're back to where you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

For the Item: `=IFERROR(INDEX(G$1:G$5,SMALL(IF(H$1:H$5<>"",ROW(G$1:G$5)-ROW(G$1)+1),ROWS(G$1:G1))),"")`

For the Qty: `=IFERROR(INDEX(H$1:H$5,SMALL(IF(H$1:H$5<>"",ROW(G$1:G$5)-ROW(G$1)+1),ROWS(G$1:G1))),"")`

Here's a screenshot of how I set up the data, so you can adjust the ranges in those formulas:

[image]

That's the formula for the Item.  The only change to get the number, is change the column in the `If` statement from `G$1:G$5` to `H$1:H$5`.

Enter these formulas as an array formula (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)
If you put these formulas and drag down a column, you can get your table updated dynamically, as IDs are added next to the Items:

[image]

And, just FYI if you want to reverse the results, just change `Small` to `Large` in the formula.