# Return Top 10 Values from a List (with Specific Conditions!)

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, limit

I have a table containing a long list of names and information. I'd like to call up the ten names with the highest values of a certain parameter, in order of 1, 2, ... 10. I already ripped a formula from past internet searches that does exactly what I want I need, and it works great. This is it:

`=INDEX(Salaries[Name],MATCH(1,INDEX((Salaries[Income]=LARGE(Salaries[Income],ROWS(C$3:C3)))*(COUNTIF(C$3:C3,Salaries[Name])=0),),0))`

This formula is copied from C4 and pasted down through C13.

I then use `=VLOOKUP($C4,Salaries,COLUMNS(Salaries[[#Headers],[Name]:[Age]]),FALSE)` and `=VLOOKUP($C4,Salaries,COLUMNS(Salaries[[#Headers],[Name]:[Income]]),FALSE)` to bring bring up the corresponding ages and incomes in columns D and E, respectively.

[image: Screenshot]

Now, I'm getting hung up on this last part. I'd like to have a user-defined age limit that will control the "Top 10" results. (Example: The user defines a maximum age of 35 and the list is populated with the names of the people with the top ten highest incomes and are also 35 years old and under.)

I know this can easily be done on the table itself by simply sorting the income column and setting a filter on the age column, but I want to have this ten-person list to be formula driven. Does anyone have any recommended edits to my existing formula or a completely different way of going about this?

[File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16VetLMCXAUYTdNN0tQU1lFUWc)

Comment: 18 making $122K, 22 making $195K... are you with Goldman Sachs?

Comment: Haha, this is just randomized data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Change your first Equation to this:

```
 =INDEX(Salaries[Name],MATCH(1,INDEX((Salaries[Income]=LARGE(IF(Salaries[Age]<= $A$3,Salaries[Income]),ROWS(C$3:C3)))*(COUNTIF(C$3:C3,Salaries[Name])=0),),0))
```

This is an array formula so confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Oh, I see what you did.. I was trying to modify the formula there myself but I wasn't getting the syntax right. I put this code it but I was getting a #N/A result. Entering it into the cell as an array, however, did the trick! Thanks! `{=INDEX(Salaries[Name],MATCH(1,INDEX((Salaries[Income]=LARGE(IF(Salaries[Age]<= $A$3,Salaries[Income]),ROWS(C$3:C3)))*(COUNTIF(C$3:C3,Salaries[Name])=0),),0))}`

Comment: @chronofreak Yeah I forgot to say that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much time, but I think I can get you on your way with a formula I've [used elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553701/formula-to-show-only-cells-with-a-value-and-remove-blank-rows/33554116#33554116):

Let's say you want your specially filtered data in columns F,G,H (starting at row 2).

Column `F` will return the "Name", `G` will return the "Age", and `H` will return the "Income".

I'm also assuming the data will be pulled from your "All Salaries" Table that starts at `C17` and goes to `C28`

In `F2`, `=IFERROR(INDEX(C$17:C$28,SMALL(IF(D$17:D$28>=35,ROW(C$17:C$28)-ROW(C$1)+1),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")`  as an array (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

In `G2`, use the same formula above, but change the first `C$17:C$28` to be `D$17:D$28`, since that is the age range.  In `H2`, use `E` instead of `D`.

That should work.  If you could paste some sample data in your OP, I can test this and double check.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but no luck. I entered in the formula as given, only changing the ranges from '17-28' to '17-92' in order to include the entire list. Not only are the results not capped at 35 yo, but the results are affected by order in which the original data is sorted. I added a link to the file in my original post. Any other ideas?